# How to enable/disable a button depending on which user is accessing the system

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to enable and disable a button depending on who accesses the system in VB.NET. When I try the below code it disables the button for all users including "jon". I am wanting Jon to login in the system with the button enabled for him.

```
If Me.TextBox1.Text = "jon" Then
    HomePage.Button4.Enabled = True
Else
    HomePage.Button4.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: It looks like this would enable the button only when jon is the text in the textbox. I wonder if you have additional spaces, or if jon is really Jon, John, etc. Can you confirm?

Comment: i am creating the system in visual studio and i have a access database linked to it and i have also have created a login page so the textbox1.text is where the user enters his user name to login. The name is written as jon in the database.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `If Me.TextBox1.Text = "jon" Then`, and debug your code. Inspect the value of `Me.TextBox1.Text` at runtime. See if there are any spaces or capitalization or special characters. If it is in fact exactly "jon", then I 100% guarantee the following code enables `HomePage.Button4`. Perhaps there's code elsewhere which disables it.

Comment: By the way, your code should not directly access UI elements from your business logic. You should have some object which encapsulates your login state, from which you can query access level, then update your UI accordingly. Business logic which accesses UI elements directly has a code smell to it.

Comment: Is HomePage really the instance or the class model.

Comment: To expand a little on djv's comment If the text box containing the user name is still accessible after login, it could be altered to the name of a user that does have access to that button without needing their password. Definitely a code smell. Also - later on if you come back to look at the code in 3 months, will you remember just by looking at it what `Button4` does? Give your controls and variables etc meaningful names.